# OpenCV Background Subtraction to Improve Detection

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm able to detect eggs on conveyor belt but the problem is, If there are no eggs on belt, algorithm still finds objects.

Detected eggs on conveyor:

[image]
[image]

If there are no eggs on belt:

[image]
  [image]

To reduce wrong detections I'm checking radius and area:

```
if (radius < 100 and radius > 20):
    ....
if area > 2200 and area < 8800:
    ....
```

But this checkpoints are not enough to prevent wrong detections.

I have tried `createBackgroundSubtractorMOG` method but I have failed detecting eggs after subtraction.

Conveyor belt types could be vary.

What is the best method for removing static background(belt) from the image?

Code:

```
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    th, bw = cv2.threshold(hsv[:, :, 2], 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
    morph = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    dist = cv2.distanceTransform(morph, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)

    borderSize = 75
    distborder = cv2.copyMakeBorder(dist, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize,
                                    cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT | cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED, 0)
    gap = 10
    kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (2*(borderSize-gap)+1, 2*(borderSize-gap)+1))
    kernel2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(kernel2, gap, gap, gap, gap,
                                    cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT | cv2.BORDER_ISOLATED, 0)

    distTempl = cv2.distanceTransform(kernel2, cv2.DIST_L2, cv2.DIST_MASK_PRECISE)

    nxcor = cv2.matchTemplate(distborder, distTempl, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)

    mn, mx, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(nxcor)
    th, peaks = cv2.threshold(nxcor, mx*0.5, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    peaks8u = cv2.convertScaleAbs(peaks)

    #fgmask = self.fgbg.apply(peaks8u)

    _,contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(peaks8u, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    peaks8u = cv2.convertScaleAbs(peaks)    # to use as mask

    for cnt in contours:
        try:
            if len(cnt) >= 5:
                (x, y), radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
                radius = int(radius)
                #print("radius: ", radius)
                if (radius < 100 and radius > 20):
                    ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
                    (center , axis, angle) = ellipse
                    cx,cy = int(center[0]),int(center[1])
                    ax1,ax2 = int(axis[0])-2,int(axis[1])-2
                    orientation = int(angle)
                    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
                    if area > 2200 and area < 8800:
                        cv2.ellipse(frame, (cx,cy), (ax1,ax2), orientation, 0, 360, (255,0,0), 2)
                        #cv2.circle(frame, (cx,cy), 1, (0, 255, 0), 15)
                        cv2.putText(frame,str(int(area)),(cx,cy), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, 0, 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Comment: Can you upload the background image as well? which you are subtracting? I guess the problem is with lighting, the background image may not be homogeneous, so when the lighting changes slightly causing shadows, etc, it detects them as eggs

Comment: Background is the belt itself. Your guess seem correct but If I can remove the belt from the image, I only can detect eggs I suppose.

Comment: Provide your code, without it we don't know what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I have added the detection code.

Comment: You’re using Otsu threshold selection. This means you will always find a foreground, whether there are eggs or not. You might be better off using a fixed threshold instead. Are eggs always white? Or do you need to handle brown eggs too? Those might have less contrast with the conveyor, making a fixed threshold less reliable.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the Otsu's to fixed thresholding, issue solved but as you said it's not reliable since I'm detecting both white and brown eggs. I'm trying to find best threshold with constant illumination. Do you have any suggestion? Do you think light color is important? Also do you think any background subtraction method fit my needs?

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic options to get the background image:

1. Obtain the background image for the specific conveyor belt in advance during some setup/calibration process.
2. Use the data itself to derive the background, for this you have to remove the objects (eggs).

The second option can be implemented by taking mean or median of every pixel over time. Given that most of the time each pixel shows background you will get a reasonably good estimate of the scene without the objects.